# Let $X_t$ be a solution of a SDE. Does the set $\{X_t \in \{p\}\}$ has null measure?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

I think this question is easy. However, I have not been able to solve it.

Let $a,\sigma:\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb R\to\mathbb{R}$, smooth functions such that $\sigma>0$. Consider the 1-dimensional SDE,
$$dX_t = a(X_t,t) dt + \sigma(X_t,t) dW_t$$
$$X_0 = x_0\in\mathbb{R}. $$
where $W_t$ is a Brownian motion.

Fixing $y\in\mathbb R$ and $t>0$, I was interested in showing that$$\mathbb{P}\left(\{\omega \in \Omega;\ X_t = y\}\right)=0.$$
Where $(\Omega,\mathcal F, \mathbb P)$, is the probability space being considered.

Does anyone know if the above equation is true? A reference would be enough for me.

Comment: Is $\sigma$ also bounded away from zero by a nonzero constant?

Comment: Not at first, but if you  provide a proof assuming this  I would be happy enough.

Comment: Maybe take a look in Section 2.2 and 2.3 of Nualart (2006): "The Malliavin Calculus and Related Topics". Theorem 2.3.1 exactly states that if the coefficients are suitably regular, see conditions (h1) and (h2) on p. 116 (classic Lipschitz conditions), then the law of $X_t$ admits density w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: See also this paper by Fournier & Printems (2010) https://arxiv.org/pdf/0804.3037.pdf